# Is it possible to track the missed connection on a socket listener?

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I build a script in Python (using Sockets and Asyncore) and it works well (and efficient), but I'm pretty sure I'm losing connections when it's bursting.

I was curious to know if there was a way to track the connections to that specific port, and how much are handled by my script, and how much are missed (doesn't respond, or respond after too long, or anything else).

I'm asking the question on SO because of the related Python code, but it can also be directly found on Linux (Debian for the matter) logs, or any implementation in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to watch for connection failures, you could use tcpdump to sniff for ICMP packets signifying a connection failure like this:

```
tcpdump -nni eth0 'port 80' -e icmp[icmptype] == 3
```

Change `eth0` to the name of your listening interface, and `'port 80'` to the port you're listening on.

Note that ICMP type 3 covers "Connection Refused" and "No Route to Host".

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know if this slows the entering requests, or not?

Comment: There's a study of that here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/10/measuring-impact-tcpdump-busy-hosts/

Comment: Wow! great, thank you. One last question and I'll be all good. Is there a way to filter for a specific port? I'm running it right now and see a lot of UDP with various port that are unreachable. I want to listen on port 80. Thanks :)

Comment: I think if you add `'port 80'` (including the quotes) after the interface name it should do that.